# approved visa for Old Passport to be stamped on New Passport

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, passport-renewals

I came to US with visiting visa  (Indian Passport holder) and I got approval for a nonimmigrant work visa. My passport is about to expire.

If I get a new passport can the approved visa be stamped on my new passport?

Comment: To clarify, are you currently in the U.S. and where did you submit your application? Have you already applied for a *visa* (i.e. a DS-160 is filled for your work visa) and got an approval for that, or have you only received a positive response to your worker petition?

Comment: currently I am in US. My application for visa is approved here. But I can get it stamped only from My country. Till then I can continue here but I have to apply DS-160 and go to US consulate in India to get it stamped. Before that If I renew my passport it will be a new one I am going with but approval is made on for my existing passport.

Comment: If you haven't applied for a visa stamp yet then it is not a problem. Just apply with your new passport when you fill DS-160.

Comment: @xngtng that sounds like an answer.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

> If I get a new passport can the approved visa be stamped on my new passport?

You cannot receive a U.S. visa stamp in the U.S., even though with the appropriate permissions you may stay legally, change your status (e.g. from visitor to worker) and start employment.

You do not need a visa to stay in the U.S. but you will have to have one if you want to visit other countries and re-enter the U.S. (in most cases).

When you actually apply for a visa sticker outside of the U.S. (using the DS-160 form), you can simply put your new passport number and use your new passport to receive your visa sticker based on your approved petition (which is issued for you as a person).

If you already submitted DS-160 or it takes a long time to renew the passport, you could try asking the consular officer during your interview to make the change (bring both passports!).

Note that the U.S. accepts valid visa stickers in expired passports; so if you cannot have your new passport in time, the old one may still be an option (if it has not expired when the visa is issued). But of course, you will need to travel with the two passports every time you want to enter the U.S. which may be a bit inconvenient.